# Where is project.properties in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android-studio

I was following this [instructions](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html) to add a library in android studio. The last step is to add the line `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in `project.properties`. I have few `.properties` files such as `local.properties`, `gradle.properties`, `cache.properties` but I can't find `project.properties` file.

Answer (score 5):

The step you're talking about is for Eclipse not Android Studio, which you have to follow only the first two instructions:

Step 1. Configure your app’s build.gradle File

Make sure you have a jcenter() entry in your repositories like so:

`repositories {
     jcenter()
   }`

add the library AAR as a dependency like so:

`dependencies {
     compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
   }`

Answer (score 2):

project.properties is a Eclipse thing and Android studio does not use project.properties file. If you need one, it has to be manually created. But it will not be used by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this file manually in project root directory, near other ".properties" files.